# If value change in content type Number Value here change

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8

(I have many content type where i need to make money convert in that content need is to make one manage field that value used in all content)

If value change in content type Number Value here change.and the number change gone use in many place
like another content type.local currency is LBP.but if customer pay in USD.i have to divide byt 1500 
because the number 1515 will use in many content.and need to change every 1 or 5 years.and it not nice to change it from each place i need one place to control number 1515.
1515 is what we use today to convert USD to local currency.

I have tried entity reference field for this but it did't worked

Comment: Your question is not clear and you have tagged both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8.

Comment: I have many content type where i need to make money convert in that content need is to make one manage field that value used in all content.